# Different behavior in Spring for reading property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, classpath

I am able to read property file in my spring application using below configuration (*note the wildcard in classpath*)

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
    <value>classpath*:*/**/test*.properties</value>
</property>
```

But when I use the same wildcard pattern to specify custom Log4j property file using the `org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener` in `web.xml` as below it fails with nasty `FileNotFoundException` and Log4j is not initialized.

Can some one help me resolve the issue and point me out what exactly I am missing here.

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:*/**/customLog4j*.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**P.S.:** I am aware of property place holders viz. `${SOME_PLACE_HOLDER}` (*where we can replace place holder value with respective system / environment property*) which can't be applied in my case as we do not have control over setting such system / environment properties and have to use wildcard to resolve the path to custom log4j property.

Comment: don't think so - `org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener` is part of spring framework which uses the `log4jConfigLocation` and not related to any specific Servlet container

Comment: Log4jConfigListener uses Log4jWebConfigurer to load configuration. Have a look at documentation on whats is valid and how to configure [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jWebConfigurer.html)

Comment: @madhav-turangi thnx that was of help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting solution for benefits of others.

[PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html#getResources(java.lang.String))'s `getResources` method resolves the wildcard classpath and returns all the match found as array of [Resource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html)

The `Resource` object then can be used accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The `Log4ConfigListener` uses `Log4jWebConfigurer` which uses `ResourceUtils` to load the `URL` from the path you specified

```
public static URL getURL(String resourceLocation) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ... // trying with prefix 'classpath:' which you don't have
    try {
        // try URL
        return new URL(resourceLocation); // this will throw malformed
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        // no URL -> treat as file path
        try {
            return new File(resourceLocation).toURI().toURL();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex2) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource location [" + resourceLocation +
                    "] is neither a URL not a well-formed file path");
        }
    }
}
```

So you get a `FileNotFoundException`. The [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jWebConfigurer.html) for `Log4jWebConfigurer` explains with examples what paths it can take. I don't think it works with wildcards.

To explain why `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` can read it: the XML bean parser reads the value `classpath*:*/**/test*.properties` in the `locations` property and generates some implementation of `ClassPathResource` which it passes to the actual bean. The wildcard behavior is included in there.

Comment: Can you share some link / resource which explains in details the implementation of XML bean parser? can use it for my custom `Log4ConfigListener` to support wildcard :)

Comment: @JavaBond There's a whole stack for that. You can try it yourself by debugging an `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` constructor. Otherwise look into the `ClassPathResource` class and its implementations.

Comment: already explored `ClassPathResource` and some of the `AbstractResource` too. None seems to work with wild cards yet :(

Comment: I would then recommend debugging `PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties()`. I believe that is where the magic happens. Look at what `fileName` variable holds.